# How to fetch href link from a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the article links in a given website below.

However, my code does not print anything at all although I specified the class id and the path to it.

below is my code.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("https://uynaa.wordpress.com/category/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%87%d1%83%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b3%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%bb/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-56456384'})
for div in productDivs:
    print(div.find('h2')[a]['href'])
```

How do I fetch all the links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links are loaded dynamically via JavaScript from external URL. You can use this example to print all links:

```
import json
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = {'action': 'infinite_scroll', 'page': 1}
api_url = 'https://uynaa.wordpress.com/?infinity=scrolling'

page = 1
while True:
    data['page'] = page
    data = requests.post(api_url, data=data).json()

    # uncomment next line to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for p in data['postflair']:
        print(p)

    if data['lastbatch']:
        break

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/2013-in-review/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%85%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%87-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%82%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d0%bd/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%82%d0%be%d0%be-%d0%b3%d1%8d/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bd/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/%d1%8d%d0%bd%d1%8d-%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d1%8e%d0%bc/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/500-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%87%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b0%d0%b3%d2%af%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%85%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d1%86%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%86/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d1%82%d2%af%d2%af%d1%85%d1%8d%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d1%8d%d1%85-%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d1%88/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%be%d1%81-%d2%af%d2%af%d0%b4%d1%8d%d0%bd-%d3%a9%d1%80%d0%bd%d3%a9%d1%85-%d0%b6%d2%af%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b3/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%b3-%d1%8d%d0%b7%d1%8d%d0%b3%d0%bd%d1%8d%d1%85-%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b4-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b3-%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d1%8d%d1%8d/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%8d%d1%8d%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d2%af%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8d%d0%bb/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%be-%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d3%a9%d0%bd%d1%86-%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d3%a9%d1%80%d0%b3%d3%a9%d1%85-%d1%91%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bb-%d1%85%d2%af%d0%bb%d1%8d%d1%8d%d0%b6-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b3-%d1%8d%d1%8d/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%87-%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd-%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b3-%d1%8b%d0%b3-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b0/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd/


...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: To filter the links only to specified category, you can use this script:

```
import json
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {'action': 'infinite_scroll', 'page': 1}
api_url = 'https://uynaa.wordpress.com/?infinity=scrolling'


all_links = []
page = 1
while True:
    data['page'] = page
    data = requests.post(api_url, data=data).json()

    # uncomment next line to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data['html'], 'html.parser')

    for p in soup.select('.post'):
        if any('%d0%be%d1%80%d1%87%d1%83%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b3%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%bb' in cat['href'] for cat in p.select('[rel="category tag"]')):
            if p.h2.a['href'] not in all_links:
                print(p.h2.a['href'])
                all_links.append(p.h2.a['href'])  

    if data['lastbatch']:
        break

    page += 1

print(len(all_links))
```

Prints 135 links:

```
...

https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/%e2%80%9c%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%83%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d2%af%d0%b5%e2%80%9d/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/%d2%af%d1%85%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bc/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%b3-%d1%8f%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%80%d2%af%d2%af%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8d%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d/
135
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is awesome, however not what I'm looking for. This finds all the links under the 'home' page, However, I am trying to find all the articles under the link, "https://uynaa.wordpress.com/category/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%87%d1%83%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b3%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%bb/"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your codes don't work. For me, I used the below codes to get all the links first.

```
list_href = []
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in a_tags:
    list_href.append(tag.get('href'))
```

The links of the articles are in list_href[5:26].

Comment: this code only gets a few of the tags. If you scroll down the page, there are about 135 article links.